# PHP - about arrays

Tags: php, arrays, string

```
$cities = array("Spain" => "Madrid","Germany" => "Berlin","USA" => array("New York", "Miami"));
foreach($cities as $city){
    echo $city.", "; }
```

The output is: Madrid, Berlin, Array
As There is 1 city from Spain, 1 from Germany and 2 from the USA(in array) it outputs array now what to do that php detects it is array and echo the parts of array.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: iterate recursively until no value is array anymore?

Answer (score 0):

`echo will not output array.` Infact it will only output `Array`.

If you want to print an array use `print_r`

Answer (score 0):

To detect if a value is an array, use `is_array`

E.g.

```
if(is_array($city)) {
    foreach($city as $sub_city) { echo 'Sub-city: ' . $sub_city; }
}
```

Comment: @verbumSapienti I wasn't writing a program for him, that's an obvious addition.

Comment: that's subjective. I included it in case the user wondered why only the array values were being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a combination of the [ternary operator](http://php.net/ternary#example-123) and [`implode()`](http://php.net/function.implode)

```
foreach($cities as $city)
{
    echo is_array($city) ? implode(', ', $city) : $city;
}
```